# Translation of "I don't have anything to smile about"

Tags: grammaire, traduction, anglais, paroles-de-chanson

I'm trying to translate the lyric: "I don't have anything to smile about."

Does

> Je n'en ai rien pour sourire

or

> Je n'ai rien pour en sourire

sound okay to you? Or would a different translation be better?

Comment: Do you mean this like an answer to "Why are you smiling?" or a more permanent sad feeling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some context would be helpful. [Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/I%20don%27t%20have%20anything%20to%20smile%20about.) is of handy here:

> Je n'ai aucune raison de sourire.
>
> Je n'ai pas de quoi sourire. (already mentioned by @petitrien)

There is also the song *[Je n'ai pas le Cœur à Sourire](https://www.paroles.net/daniel-guichard/paroles-je-n-ai-pas-le-coeur-a-sourire)* of Daniel Guichard

> Je n'ai pas le cœur à sourire

(already mentioned by @MercrediAndThenJedi)

Besides, in this link

https://genius.com/Genius-traductions-francaises-halsey-nightmare-traduction-francaise-lyrics

one reads the original lyrics of the song *Nightmare* by Halsey along the French translation. So

> No, I ain't got nothin' to smile about.
>
> Non, je n'ai pas de quoi sourire.

Here is the Pre-chorus

> "Come on, little lady, give us a smile" - "Allez, petite fille, fais-nous un sourire"
>
> No, I ain't got nothin' to smile about - Non, je n'ai pas de quoi sourire
>
> I got no one to smile for, I waited a while for -Je n'ai personne à qui sourire, j'ai attendu un certain temps pour
>
> A moment to say I don't owe you a goddamn thing - Un moment pour dire que je ne te dois rien

Answer (score 5):

In this case, I'd rather say:

> 1. Je n'ai pas le coeur à (sou)rire
> 2. Je n'ai pas le coeur à en (sou)rire

Comment: That seems wrong to me: "Je n'ai pas le coeur à sourire" implies a rather temporary situation, while "I don't have anything to smile about" is more permanent.

Comment: @Blackhole : "*I've lost [ beloved one ], I don't have anything to smile about.*" is = to "*Je viens de perdre [ être cher ], je n'ai pas le coeur à sourire*", and this doesn't imply any time-frame. Only lasting as long as your sorrow will last. Be it in English or French, to me, the meaning is the same.

Comment: "Pas le coeur a" makes it about you. "I don't have anything" makes it about the situation. It changes the meaning, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Neither translation is working.  *en* for some reason doesn't work here as a pronoun for the object of *sourire* and *rien* is problematic too.  I think you'd have to say :

- > Je n'ai pas de quoi sourire

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just:

> Plus rien ne me fait sourire.

Comment: That's "Nothing makes me smile any more."

Comment: Grosso modo c'est le sens et le sentiment, hein ? :)

Comment: Dans ce cas, à quoi sert « any more » dans  « "I don't have anything to smile about any more. » ? C'est aller trop loin de l'ajouter dans la traduction.

Comment: Attends, any more ou anymore ?  Chez Cosette ?

Comment: « anymore » en américain et « any more » en anglais mais le premier est probablement accepté en anglais aussi.

Comment: Tout ce que je connais c'est le « chat » sur une question particulière.

Comment: "Nothing makes me smile any more [than that]," ça exprime du bonheur.  Si c'est américain ou anglais j'ignore la différence.  Par contre, ...« anymore » ça veut dire ne...plus. Oui voilà je ne veux pas m'abuser des commentaires, pardon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97369/discussion-between-livresque-and-lph).

Answer (score 2):

The two translations are grammatical French but they do not correspond to the context and the contexts that justify them are so far fetched that those sentences will never occur in the language ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+n%27en+ai+rien+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20n%27en%20ai%20rien%3B%2Cc0)).

There are several possibilities of translation; I think there'll be yet others besides those listed below;

- Il n'y a rien qui me fasse sourire.
- Il n'y a rien qui me porte à sourire.
- Je ne trouve pas quoi que ce soit qui me fasse sourire.
- Je n'y trouve pas  quoi que ce soit qui me fasse sourire.
- Pour moi, il n'y a pas de quoi sourire.

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand: https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/je+n%27en+ai+rien.html One encounters a lot of **
Je n'en ai rien** not to say "...will never occur in the language".

Comment: I am not a native speaker but I cannot imagine a native one (even coming from Sorbonne:-)!) to prefer **Je ne trouve pas quoi que ce soit qui me fasse sourire.** than **Je n'ai pas de quoi sourire** in colloquial speech.

Comment: @Dimitris Slight variations in the context might make that preferable but that is not even necessary; all people do not choose the shortest way there is to express what they have to say. 1/  « Je ne trouve pas » insists on the fact that the person does not see anything but that in the end there might be something that they missed (for instance). 2/ There is nothing specially formal in this form, it's quite common; the subjunctive is a commonly found in everyday speech in French, provided one does not restrict their consideration to the least educated portion of the population, of course.

Comment: @Dimitris Anyway, consider this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=n%27ai+pas+de+quoi+sourire%2Ca+pas+de+quoi+sourire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20pas%20de%20quoi%20sourire%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Sorry I have been working in an academic environment for several years and I can certainly say that even prof usually prefer the shortest way to express an idea.

Comment: Ngram is not panacea:-)!  According to your link https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+n%27en+ai+rien+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20n%27en%20ai%20rien%3B%2Cc0 there is no an instance encountered of je n'en ai rien; nevertheless https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/je+n%27en+ai+rien.html shows that this is not the case.

Comment: (By the way I gave a positive vote:-)!). Consider the sentence "Vous savez maintenant en quoi consiste ce travail de déconstruction, je n'ai rien à ajouter à cela." Why someone would prefer instead in everyday discussion "Vous savez maintenant en quoi consiste ce travail de déconstruction, il n'y a rien que je puisse ajouter * ?

Comment: @Dimitris You should understand, it seems to me, that if you do not find "n'ai pas de quoi sourire" even more so you are not going to find "je n'ai pas de quoi sourire".

Comment: @Dimitris Heureusement qu'il y a des gens comme vous pour réparer un peu les injustices ! Il n'y a pas une très grande différence dans les deux formes que vous comparez : elle pourrait être rendue précise si nécessaire en demandant et la réponse pourrait être : « je ne le souhaite pas » ou « je n'en ai pas la possibility » ; mais les deux formes sont acceptables et parfois dans un contexte particulier on comprendra même de laquelle il s'agit.

Answer (score 2):

Two idiomatic phrases that may suit your purpose:

> Il n'y a (vraiment) pas de quoi sourire.
>
> Il n'y a (vraiment) pas de quoi rire.

This usually applies to a specific situation.

This phrase was used as [title of a book](https://www.rtl.fr/culture/arts-spectacles/il-n-y-a-pas-de-quoi-rire-une-anthologie-des-derniers-textes-de-raymond-devos-7783667805), which is a collection of sketches by Raymond Devos.

Answer (score 1):

- Je ne trouve pas ça [drôle / rigolo / marrant] (du tout).
- Cela ne me fait pas (vraiment) [rire / rigoler] (du tout).
- C'est pas [drôle / rigolo / marrant] (du tout)!